# Can't get to work Laravel models with many relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables with quite complex relationships. Table `users` has two foreign keys to table `images` and table `images` has one foreign key to table `users` which is unrelated to other two foreign keys.

I can't make correctly models. I need so that all referenced fields are associated with models and also so that there is `images` property in `User` which returns all images owned by that user.
Here is my table generating code:

```
Schema::create('users', function ($table) {
  $table->increments('id')->unsigned();

  $table->integer('portrait')->unsigned()->nullable();
  $table->integer('backimg')->unsigned()->nullable();

  $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('images', function ($table) {
  $table->increments('id')->unsigned();

  $table->integer('owner')->unsigned();
  $table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('users');

  $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::table('users', function($table) {
  $table->foreign('portrait')->references('id')->on('images');
  $table->foreign('backimg')->references('id')->on('images');
});
```

And here is my try with models:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    public function backimg(){
        return $this->hasOne('Image', 'backimg');
    }
    public function portrait(){
        return $this->hasOne('Image', 'portrait');
    }
    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Image', 'owner');
    }
}
class Image extends Eloquent {
    public function owner(){
        return $this->hasOne('User', 'owner');
    }
}
```

I thought that code above should work, however all properties return strings not objects.

Comment: Side note: `->nullable()->default(null)` is redundant, you don't need the default in there.

Comment: @TimLewis I know, I wrote it so that it will be easy to change to something other afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't name the relationships the same as the name of your foreign key columns!

Changing either one should work, however I suggest you change the foreign key columns to `owner_id`, `portrait_id` etc... Then you also don't need to specify the foreign key column in your relation since you're using the conventional names.

Comment: Those aren't foreign key names - they are column names. Laravel automatically names foreign keys adding table name before.

Comment: Sorry I actually meant the name of your foreign key columns

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand how field renaming from `portrait` to `portrait_id` will help. Can you provide an example please?

Comment: The problem is that they collide with the relationship properties. So when you do `$user->portrait` you get the value of the foreign key column because Laravel will check for non-relationship attributes first. Know what I mean?